# How to fix drop FPS when smoke on screen in Counter Strike

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I have a gaming laptop and my drivers are updated.
Usually, I'm playing with 200+ FPS, but since the last CS:GO update, when a smoke pops on the screen I drop to 30-40 FPS. I'm playing with an AWP and when I zoom in it is horrible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the "one-way smoke fix" smoke effects have become extremely demanding on GPUs pixel fill rate.

Most likely the problem is the quite poor pixel fill rate (13.6 GPixel/s) of the GTX 765M. In comparison to the GTX 770 with 33.5 GPixel/s or even the 4 years old GTX 570 with 29.3 GPixel/s.

The only fix is to lower your resolution.

Comment: Will try this solution, but I'm playing on 1600x900, instead of 1920x1080 because I prefer to play like this. I don't know which resolution could I chose if I want to keep graphical quality and perfect crosshair. Will give you a feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a different DirectX level
[(Command Line Options)](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Command_Line_Options#Command-line_parameters)

> -dxlevel  - Forces a specific DirectX version when launching the engine. This is useful if your graphics card is DirectX 9 capable, but a lot faster using only DirectX 8 (e.g. NVidia GeForce FX 5200). Multiply the desired DirectX version to use with ten. E.g. for DirectX 8.0 you would use -dxlevel 80. For DX9 there are three possible values depending on the Shader Model the graphics card supports. Seemat_dxlevel.

Comment: Thanks for advise :) I will try ! But it seems me strange because before some updates of the game, I didn't have issues like this ! And I've never launched a game on D8 haha ! I have a GTX 765M 2Go, I can run GTA V easily etc.

Comment: @HugoTor Might be some updates to the shaders that for some reasons are causing a slowdown. Good luck!

Comment: Maybe I should wait for the next update from NVidia or Valve.. ^^